# Cloning of rows and columns from the old table into the new with colSpan and rowSpan

Tags: jquery, html-table, clone, rows

I am using clone jQuery. It is necessary to clone a gray area in the new table.
The problem is that the cloned rows and columns can has rowSpan and colSpan.

The gray area is the intersection data-fix-cols and data-fix-rows.

My solution does not work:

```
<table id="old-table" data-fix-cols='3' data-fix-rows='4'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="gray">CLONE ME</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="gray">CLONE ME</td>
            <td>Ashgabat</td>
            <td>Barcelona</td>
            <td>Berlin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" class="gray">CLONE ME</td>
            <td>Bucharest</td>
            <td>Warsaw</td>
            <td>Washington</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="gray">CLONE ME</td>
            <td class="gray">CLONE ME</td>
            <td>Hamburg</td>
            <td>Guatemala</td>
            <td>Dakar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="gray">CLONE ME</td>
            <td class="gray">CLONE ME</td>
            <td>Dresden</td>
            <td>Dublin</td>
            <td>Geneva</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zagreb</td>
            <td>Kinshasa</td>
            <td>Kishinev</td>
            <td>Krakow</td>
            <td>Lima</td>
            <td>Lisbon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>Los Angeles</td>
            <td>Luxembourg</td>
            <td>Madrid</td>
            <td>Manila</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Milan</td>
            <td>Montreal</td>
            <td>Mumbai</td>
            <td>Nairobi</td>
            <td>Nicosia</td>
            <td>New York</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Osaka</td>
            <td>Oslo</td>
            <td>Ottawa</td>
            <td>Paris</td>
            <td>Prague</td>
            <td>Riga</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rome</td>
            <td>Rotterdam</td>
            <td>Salvador</td>
            <td>Samarkand</td>
            <td>Sydney</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sofia</td>
            <td>Istanbul</td>
            <td>Taipei</td>
            <td>Tbilisi</td>
            <td>Zurich</td>
            <td>Chicago</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="new-table"></table>
```

JavaScript code:

```
var old_table = $("#old-table");
var my_clone = $('#old-table tbody').clone();
var fix_cols = old_table.data('fix-cols');
var fix_rows = old_table.data('fix-rows');

fix_cols--;
fix_rows--;

my_clone.find('tr:gt(' + fix_rows + ')').remove();
my_clone.find('tr').each(function(i,e)
{
    my_clone.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('td:gt(' + fix_cols + ')').remove();
});

$('#new-table').html(my_clone);
$('#new-table').show();
```

In example http://jsfiddle.net/djmartini/u8ov43tn/5/

Comment: You want to clone the grey area to the new table?

Comment: you need to set background-color property to set background color, not bgcolor

Comment: I want to clone the rows and columns in the new table, the old table marked with gray, intersection data-fix-cols = '3' data-fix-rows = '4b
that is, a new table will be 3x4

Comment: You need to remove these tds out of the view right? 'Bucharest Warsaw'

Comment: Yes, it should remain just that has a gray background

Comment: Here you have set bgcolor just for reference, in real code you can't have that property right?

Comment: I ordered it to be clear that it is necessary to clone

Comment: @djmartini didn't get you, why you set that bgcolor? would you be please more clear with that...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartini/u8ov43tn/5/

Comment: my_clone.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('td:not(.gray)').remove(); Is this useful? or not at all?

Comment: No! Class .rgay for example, to make it clear what is to be cloned.
I wrote, it is necessary to clone the intersection based on the data attributes

Comment: Ohkey gotcha, Trying to find out proper and better solution

Answer (score 3):

This fiddle contains your required answer
http://jsfiddle.net/u8ov43tn/13/

```
var old_table = $("#old-table");
var my_clone = $('#old-table tbody').clone();
var fix_cols = old_table.data('fix-cols');
var fix_rows = old_table.data('fix-rows');

//fix_cols--;
fix_rows--;
var tDsInRow = [];
my_clone.find('tr:gt(' + fix_rows + ')').remove();
my_clone.find('tr').each(function (i, e) {
    if (typeof tDsInRow[i] == "undefined") {
        tDsInRow[i] = fix_cols;
    }

    my_clone.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('td:lt(' + fix_cols + ')').each(function (j, td) {

        if (td.colSpan > 1 && td.rowSpan > 1) {
            tDsInRow[i] = tDsInRow[i] - (td.colSpan - 1)
            for (var j = 1; j < td.rowSpan; j++) {
                if (typeof tDsInRow[i + j] == "undefined") {
                    tDsInRow[i + 1] = fix_cols;
                }

                tDsInRow[i + j] = tDsInRow[i + j] - (td.colSpan)
            }
        } else if (td.colSpan > 1) {
            tDsInRow[i] = tDsInRow[i] - (td.colSpan - 1)
        } else if (td.rowSpan > 1) {
            for (var j = 1; j < td.rowSpan; j++) {
                if (typeof tDsInRow[i + j] == "undefined") {
                    tDsInRow[i + j] = fix_cols;
                }

                tDsInRow[i + j] = tDsInRow[i + j] - (td.colSpan)
            }
        }
    });
});

my_clone.find('tr').each(function (i, e) {
    if (tDsInRow[i] > 0) {
        my_clone.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('td:gt(' + (tDsInRow[i] - 1) + ')').remove();
    } else {
        my_clone.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('td').remove();
    }
});

$('#new-table').html(my_clone);

$('#new-table').show();
```

Comment: Well played sir. I was taking a different approach of parsing the HTML. [This is as far as I got](http://jsfiddle.net/esfh47d5/2/).

Comment: @Parag Bhayani  Your solution does not work for example:  data-fix-cols='1' data-fix-rows='4'

Comment: @djmartini : Updated answer solves that problem as well, Fiddle link -> http://jsfiddle.net/u8ov43tn/13/

Comment: @Parag Bhayani   so it decides, but the decision ksozhaleniyu not universal, here is an example where it does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartini/u8ov43tn/16/

Comment: Yahh, there will be lots of cases that are needed to be check, my solution will just give you rough idea how to approach for the solution, For some corner cases you need to write some more code and logics -> Here is a solution for your requirements -> http://jsfiddle.net/u8ov43tn/20/